# diverging implicit expansion issue with Ordering Type Class from Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit

Play with Ordering from `scala package` or more precisely  `scala.math.Ordering`.

I'm toying with implicit resolution and find a case that i can't explain.

So I have the following that works like charm expected for the last line which act funny:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
import Ordering._


1 equiv 2


List[Int](1) < List[Int](2)


scala.Option[Int](1) < scala.Option[Int](1)


(Some(1):scala.Option[Int]) < (Some(2):scala.Option[Int])
```

So written as such:

```
(Some(1):scala.Option[Int]) < (Some(2):scala.Option[Int])
```

the last line works fine.

But if i write

```
Some(1) < Some(2)
```

I get

> diverging implicit expansion for type java.util.Comparator[Some[Int]]
> starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait
> LowPriorityOrderingImplicits Some(1) < Some(2)

Can't understand the issue

`import Ordering.Implicits._` give me the `infixOrderingOps syntax` which work well for everything else, as i also make sure to bring in scope all the "typeclass instances" with `import Ordering._`

Ordering the Option exist, Some is a subtype of Option, so what's the issue ?

Comment: `Ordering` is **invariant** so even if `Some[A] <: Option[A]` is true, `Ordering[Some[A]] <: Ordering[Option[A]]` is not true. - BTW, unless for some advanced typelevel programming techniques, the fact that `Some` as a **type** is useless and some consider it an error; in **Scala 3** the expression `Some(1)` will return a value of **type** `Option[Int]`. - I am not answering the question because this is probably a duplicate but I am too lazy to search for the dup.

Comment: Corrects is `import Ordering.Implicits._`. It's not supposed to be imported like `import Ordering._` (`Ordering` is a companion object, anyway implicits from there are in the implicit scope for `Ordering[...]`, aparently with `import Ordering._` you increased priority of some implicits and this led to `diverging implicit expansion for type java.util.Comparator[Some[Int]] starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits`). So with `import Ordering.Implicits._` you have correct error `value < is not a member of Some[Int]`. Luis explained why.